# How to solve Mac "Holding for Authentication" when printer does not have credentials

Tags: macos, mac, printing, printer, cups

I have a printer hosted (CUPS) on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine so that everyone on the network can use it, and it just works on all computers after a quick setup. On a certain mac however, it was working but now says "Holding for Authentication." Most websites say to remove the key in the keychain for the printer, but since there never was authentication, there is no key to remove, and pressing the reload icon doesn't do anything.

Comment: It sounds as if the authentication issue is with the Ubuntu PC. Have you tried logging into it to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: There's also this link: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/15185/printing-on-hold-for-authentication-first-time-only

Comment: I have tried logging in as I went into the web panel for CUPS while the issue was happening, and was successfully able to print things from my other devices; The mac device was the only one that stopped working.